# How to select 2nd smallest values in rows and return their respective column names?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix, min

I have a dataframe with lots of columns with lots of integer values in it. I want to return the name of the column, for the second lowest values in the row.

I am able to return the column name for the lowest value in a row which is pretty simple:

```
import pandas as pd

matrix = [(22, 2, 13),
          (9, 1, 5),
          (5, 4, 3),
          (6, 3, 1),
          (1, 2, 20)]

dfObj = pd.DataFrame(matrix, index=list('abcde'), columns=list('xyz'))

minValueIndexObj = dfObj.idxmin(axis=1)
print("min values of row are at following columns :")
print(minValueIndexObj)

Out[]:
min values of row are at following columns :
a    y
b    y
c    z
d    z
e    x
dtype: object
```

Row 'a' has the column 'y' with the lowest value.

What I need next would be:

```
2nd min values of row are at following columns :
a    z
b    z
c    y
d    y
e    y
dtype: object
```

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) for array of all columns names by sorted values:

```
a = dfObj.columns.values[np.argsort(dfObj.values)]
print (a)
[['y' 'z' 'x']
 ['y' 'z' 'x']
 ['z' 'y' 'x']
 ['z' 'y' 'x']
 ['x' 'y' 'z']]
```

Then select `'columns'` by indexing and pass to `Series` constructor:

```
print (pd.Series(a[:, 0], index=dfObj.index))
a    y
b    y
c    z
d    z
e    x
dtype: object

print (pd.Series(a[:, 1], index=dfObj.index))
a    z
b    z
c    y
d    y
e    y
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped! So if I would concatenate the column in question to the dataframe, I would just go ```dfObj[2nd] = a[:,1]```, right?

Comment: @Audiogott - yes, exactly.

Comment: May I ask you one more question: now that I have a column with row names, how can I match the row name back to the value? For example with lowest values: ```a -> y; y -> 2```.